# Create manual log in SQL Server 2012 and SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I have a `SSIS` Package that will delete the records from `Data Warehouse`. Before deleting the data, Package will create a `Snapshot tables` and insert the record that needs to be deleted into `Snapshot tables`. And finally delete the record and count the total deleted record. 
I created the dynamic query to insert and delete the record which is then used as a `stored procedure` inside a `For-each Loop` of `SSIS` Package.

Now i need to create a `log` of Deleted and Inserted record. For example : how many rows are inserted, how many rows are deleted, Start date , end date , success/failure and so on. 
I need to create one log table that will have both `SQL Server` query log and `SSIS` Package log.

Please advise how can i perform logging in this case.

Comment: What feature is missing from [Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server) that caused you to dismiss that as an option and roll your own solution instead?

Comment: What is Change Data Capture ? Could you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this type of scenario ,few of them which is well known listed below ,please check and let me know in case of any confusion.

**1**. Change Data Cpature (CDC) In `SSIS`(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/change-data-capture/change-data-capture-ssis?view=sql-server-ver15][1]).

**2**. Take the count of record at the time of insertion and deletion and assign this to a variable using `Execute SQL Task`.

**3**. Take the count of record at the time of insertion and deletion and Insert the count into a table.

There are many more ways but this is common one , please try this logic and let me know if your purpose is resolved.